# Google Map api V3 storing inputs

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a site in which you can right click on the map and it will add marker in which you can add some information. Then that information will be stored in a *.php (so it will have cords and the information linked to the marker in that php). Every time you reload the page it will load the map + the markers from the php.

My question is : How to do that...?
I'm really new to this. So if anyone can help it would be awesome.
This is my basic code I have (only the scrip  aka I know I have to input javascripts etc)

```
function initialize() {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.4860277885627, -2.2480342915039273);
//^ don't mind this

var myOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  minZoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3.html) for saving to a MySQL database with PHP.